# Excel If column A has same value then highlight max date in column B

Tags: excel, ms-office, conditional-formatting

Looking for Excel conditional formatting help.

Need to highlight Max Date from Column B if Column A has same values.
For Example; in column A value of "16870288"; "2018/07/20" should be highlighted in column B.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You couldn't have select B3, B5 and B7 and clicked the Home, Font, Fill Color button ...?

Comment: List is much longer than what I posted.

Comment: have you tried using a pivot table with the account id in rows and the max date in values? instead of conditional formatting

Comment: I meant in your sample. Leaving the highlights out just adds to the confusion your narrative creates.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted as shown (ie ColumnA grouped together and within that ColumnB ascending), then a CF formula rule of:

```
=A2<>A3
```

applied in B2 and to the range B2:Bn where `n` is what suits, should serve.

Comment: But it doesn't highlight the max date in column B, 

So I selected column A and Column B; then a new rule in conditional formatting and entered your given formula, but it doesn't highlight max date.

Answer (score 0):

Create a conditional formatting rule for column B based on a MAXIFS formula. If you don't have the newer MAXIFS function, create a pseudo-MAXIFS with INDEX or AGGREGATE.

```
=AND($B1<>"", $B1=AGGREGATE(14, 7, B:B/($A$1:$A$9999=$A1), 1))
```

[image]